# Spring boot Jackson date format is not working

Tags: spring, date, spring-boot, jackson, format

```
        @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private Integer id;


        @Column(nullable = true)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date date_start;

        @Column(nullable = true)
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date date_end;
```

My entity name "test"
there are columns for date_start and date_end..
i set DateTimeFormat annotation and type is Date...

```
 @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createStudy(@RequestBody DateCreateVO dateCreateVO, HttpServletRequest request) {

 System.out.println(dateCreateVO.getDate_start());
}
```

However this sout result is "2019-03-18" 
but i want to get "2019-03-18 12:14:52"

therefore i set

```
jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd　HH:mm:ss
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

in application.yml

but it's still not working :(

please help me to solve this problem !

Is there any some code that i should write in application.yml ???

Comment: You are actually storing date     by annotating with @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") and you are expecting  "yyyy-MM-dd　HH:mm:ss". Try it by changing the date pattern with  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")

Comment: Thank you for answer but even if i change to @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) it's still not working :(